# PHP connection "Failed to get DB handle: could not find driver"

Tags: php, sql-server, xampp

I'm using the following code to try and connect:

```
try {
        $hostname = "*****";
        $port = 1443;
        $dbname = "*******";
        $username = "********";
        $pw = "************";
        $dbh = new PDO ("dblib:host=$hostname:$port;dbname=$dbname","$username","$pw");
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            echo "Failed to get DB handle: " . $e->getMessage() . "\n";
        exit;
        }
```

This is my Error:

```
Failed to get DB handle: could not find driver
```

And the **DLL Files** are already in the **php/ext** and modified in the **php.ini**

What else can I do?

Comment: Have you tried to restart your web server ?

Comment: Yes but its still the same Problem.

Comment: The PDO Driver is enabled

Comment: Try this code:
`echo "<pre>", print_r(PDO::getAvailableDrivers()), "</pre>";`
So you can see what for drivers are available..

Answer (score -1):

There is following of possibility here,

1. enable mssql in php.ini

   `;extension=php_mssql.dll`

   to
   `extension=php_mssql.dll`
2. try editing your setting at the php.ini **mssql.secure_connection** must be set to **on**.
   mssql_connect can use secured connection if php is configured ...
   go into the php.ini and verify the mssql.secure_connection parameter

   `[MSSQL]`
   `mssql.secure_connection = On`
   3.Try this:

Uncomment the following in php.ini by removing the ";"

```
;extension=php_pgsql.dll
```

I hope this will help you.

Comment: I tried it both. But I have still the same problem.

Comment: I'm very sorry but I have still the same Problem :(

Comment: PHP version 7.0+ doesn't come with the mssql library listed in this comment. php_pgsql.dll is for PostgresQL.